# Excel: combine columns in different sheets matching informations

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in Excel.

The structure of the first one is:

```
A           B               C               D                   E           F               G           H
mail        firstname       lastname        date_of_birth       school      classroom       teacher     type
--@--.com   ------          ----            2000-12-20          ----        ---             ----        -----
```

In the second sheet I have the replies to a survey, for which I collected the email addresses and names of the students.

```
A           B               C               D                   E           F               G           H
Name        mail            question1       question2           question3   question4       question5   question6
```

I need to combine the informations in the first and second sheets to create a new sheet with all the columns of the first sheet and the columns starting from C of the second sheet.
Of course I need to match the rows to have the correct questions attached to the row of the corresponding student. The two sheets are not ordered in the same way (and I can't order by name because some didn't reply to the survey).
The criteria of the matching needs to be based on: 1. email and 2. name (CONCATENATING THE firstname and lastname of first sheet and then matching with the column "name" of the second sheet.), in this order (first check is matching by email, if this fails name is a fallback check).

How can I achieve this in Excel (2013)? Is there a function or a formula?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new worksheet, A2:H2 could be simply,

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

Fill right to Sheet3!H2. Sheet3!I2 would be,

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet2!$B:$H, match(I$1, Sheet2!$B$1:$H$1, 0), FALSE), VLOOKUP($B2&" "&$C2, Sheet2!$A:$H, match(I$1, Sheet2!$A$1:$H$1, 0), FALSE)), "")
```

Fill right to Sheet3!N2 then fill Sheet3!A2:N2 down to catch all available records.

I've concatenated the *firstname* and *lastname* from Sheet1 with a space to match Sheet2's *Name*. It could be *lastname*&", "&*firstname*.

Comment: Hey! :) Thanks for the reply!! I tried the formulas but I get "N/A".. Here I set up the exact same sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOrPllOw68EzMFbfPl57m9TyQ5XG49-YWm8Tq2nfDvU/edit?pli=1#gid=555679618

Comment: What's the reference to I$1?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno - I1 should be *question1*, J1 should be *question2*, etc.

Comment: PERFECT! It works :)
Last thing: is it possible to have a blank output instead of "N/A" if match is not successful?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno - Wrap the whole formula(s) in another `IFERROR`, returning a zero length string if not found. (see above) Alternately, wrap only the second `VLOOKUP` in the same sort of `IFERROR`.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno - BTW, I built the secondary `VLOOKUP` formulas that way to demonstrate that you can lookup any column in any order using `MATCH` to find the column to return. All you have to do is add or change the header column label to match what you want to return.